# Pointers in C, out of the code below

Tags: c, pointers

What should be the output of the code below?
I cant understand what *Y-- do. If someone can explain what *Y do this strange thin in F1. Thanks in advance.

```
int F1(int , int *);
int A = 3;
int B = 7;
int C = 4; 
int D = 2;

void main(void)
{

    A = F1 (C, &D);
    printf("\n%d %d %d %d", A, B, C, D);
    C = 3;
    C = F1 (A, &C);
    printf("\n%d %d %d %d", A, B, C, D);
}

int F1(int X, int *Y)
{
    int A;
    A = X * *Y;
    C++;
    B += *Y;
    printf("\n%d %d %d %d", A, B, C, D);
    *Y--;
    return (C);
}
```

with CodeBlocks the output is :

```
8 9 5 2
5 9 5 2
15 13 4 2
5 13 4 2
```

But I dont understand why 13, if I have B=B+*Y ...B=12 (?)

Comment: `*Y` is the variable pointed to by `Y`. In the function call `F1(C, &D)`, the parameter `X` takes *the value* of `C`, and the parameter `Y` takes *the address* of `D`; so in the body of the function `X` is an ordinary local variable initialized with the value of `C`, and `*Y` is the same thing as the global variable `D`.

Comment: Format your code properly for starters. Second, run the program to see the outputs yourself. You can use https://ideone.com to do this online. Thirdly, please read a basic C tutorial to understand the unary `*` operator.

Comment: With the compiler online I got this:                                                                            8 9 5 2
5 9 5 2
15 13 4 2
5 13 4 2 But I cant understand why 13 in the third line.

Comment: your compiler will complain when it sees those stupid [smart quotes `“”`](https://www.fonts.com/content/learning/fyti/typographic-tips/smart-quotes). change to normal quotes

Answer (score 0):

**A = 5, B = 9, C = 3, D = 2** before calling `C = F1(A, &C) ;`

when we make call to `F1(A, &C)` see here we are passing address of **C**, now Y is actually referencing to **C** .

*Instruction Execution in function call*

local A variable = 5 * 3 (**value at which Y pointing**)

*C++, Global C now becomes 4 ;*

B += *Y (value at which Y pointing. this will be 4 because of previous C
++)

*so B = 9 + 4*. It is the reason for 13 in third line .